# How can I declare list in gradle.properties file?

Tags: gradle

When I try to write something like this in the gradle.properties file:

```
defaultTasks=['deploy']
```

I get next message:

```
BUILD FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:
Cannot cast object '['deploy']' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose, it's not possible to make it this way, because this is a plain java properties and the property value is a String by default. But you can add some initialization logic to your script, to read custom properties and use them to initialize the `defaultTasks` property.

Add a custom property into the `gradle.properties` file

```
extDefaultTasks=temp1,temp2
```

`temp1` and `temp2` are task names (this tasks should exists). And in the build script, read this property, parse it and initialize `defaultTasks` with it:

```
//load custom property value and split it into the task names
def String[] tasksToUseAsDefault = extDefaultTasks.split(',')
//use task names to initialize defaultTasks
tasksToUseAsDefault.each {defaultTasks.add(it.trim())}
```

This configuration should be added into to the root of the script, in order to be done at the configuration phase of the build

Answer (score 2):

### The values in `.properties` files are always read as `String`s.

You can just declare the array in your `.properties` file like the following.

```
defaultTasks=deploy,build,run,compile 
// or just defaultTasks=deploy if you have only one task
```

And convert it into an `Array` in your `.gradle` file like the following.

```
tasks = properties.getProperty("defaultTasks").split(",")
```