# Gradle 'include' or 'exclude' List of strings

Tags: gradle, groovy, build

My jar dir structure is as below.

```
myDir
- /util/Util.jar
- /abcd/abcd.jar
- /parsing_jars/pars.jar
```

Expected `anotherDir` structure should be as below

```
anotherDir
- Util.jar
- abcd.jar
- pars.jar
```

I'm using below syntax for my copy task as

```
task('copyUtil', type: Copy) {
    fileTree("$projectDir/myDir").each { file ->
        if (file.isFile())
            from file
    }
    include 'Util.jar', 'abcd.jar', 'pars.jar'
    into "anotherDir"
}
```

It works fine, but if I define variable in properties file as

```
MY_VAR = '"Util.jar", "abcd.jar", "pars.jar"'
```

It treats it as a whole string and doesn't include any file.. How can provide this `MY_VAR` to `copy` task as below?

```
task('copyUtil', type: Copy) {
    fileTree("$projectDir/myDir").each { file ->
        if (file.isFile())
            from file
    }
    include "${MY_VAR}"
    into "anotherDir"
}
```

**Please Note:** I tried to convert that string into `List` or `Array` both doesn't work... basically it need the comma separated args.. `include` Javadoc says `public AbstractCopyTask include(String... includes)`

**like below doesn't work here:**

```
def String[] tasksToUseAsDefault = "${SOME_VAR}".split(',')
```

Or

```
def list = Arrays.asList("${SOME_VAR}".split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I declare list in gradle.properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808495/how-can-i-declare-list-in-gradle-properties-file)

Comment: Nope, I tried to convert that string into `List` or `Array` both doesn't work... basically it need the comma separated args.. `include` Javadoc says `public AbstractCopyTask include(String... includes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_65003496).

With `gradle.properties` like so:

```
MY_VAR = Util.jar, abcd.jar, pars.jar
```

Consider this task:

```
task('copyUtil', type: Copy) {
    // ["**/Util.jar", "**/abcd.jar", ...]
    def matchStr = MY_VAR.split(",").collect{"**/" + it.trim()}

    from fileTree(".").include(matchStr).files
    into "anotherDir"
}
```

Comment: Hi @michael-easter yes, your solution works perfectly if it run as it is but I missed some important thing in my question. So, the provided solution doesn't work with `filetree` structure. I've updated my question with `filetree` structure. Could you please check it and help me with that? Apologies for not clarifying the question at very first.

Comment: the `filetree` is used to `flattern` the directory structure

Comment: Please update the question with the structure of `myDir` and the desired structure of `anotherDir` (i.e. subfolders, etc). This may help us understand why there is a need to flatten. I believe the question is not fully described.

Comment: I have updated GitHub and the answer. Please accept and upvote any answer if it answers your question.